# How to split up/crop overlapping letter image python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have a sub image in file, each image i want to split overlap letter in this image into each letter. For example, in the first picture i want separate to 3 and 4, the second is F N and so on....

I uses **Morphological Transformations (Python)** but it loss so much information because each image have difference Morphological Transformations.

So plz help me!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is lengthy and cannot be solved in a few lines of code.

However, here is a guide of my method I can think of to solve this problem.

- Find contours in the image with the RETR_EXTERNAL flag to the detection of the inner area of the letters(like the inner white part of D, 4, 6, 9, etc.).
- Now draw this contour on a separate new image with thickness = -1. This will give you the numbers filled with colour(without inner part separately coloured).
- NOTE: A general way of separating objects is using erosion and dilation but in this case, the letters are themselves thin due to which on erosion/dilation, they themselves will break.
- To get around the above problem mentioned, the way is to first fill the letters and enclosed area which will give 2 boxes joined from near a point.
- An easy solution to this would be finding convex hull for the contour. But this will fail too(Cannot explain without a demo).
- Thus to find the points of edginess, [refer to this research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222152083_Automated_separation_of_touching_grains_in_digital_images_of_thin_sections)
- After finding these wedge points, fill the letters near the wedge points.
- Now perform erosion and dilation and find point where the contours are breaking.
- Draw a line there in the original image and again find contours.
- You will now probably have 2 contours for both letters.